# NavigationController Xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin.ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am using the navigation controllers to manage the storyboards of my xamarin.ios project, I am in the situation where from a dynamic prototypes table (with table source cell is customized), I have to switch to a viewcontroller driven with NavigationControllers, thus treating the navigation bar not appears making me lose the ability to go back to the previous controller.

```
public void ApriStoryBoard(string x)
    {
        var storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);
        var viewController = storyboard.InstantiateViewController(x); // Your view controller here

        UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController = viewController;
    }
```

i am currently trying with PushViewController, but it doesn't work ..

```
 public void ApriNavigationController()
    {
        ThisSchedaView x = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("QuestaSchedaNav") as ThisSchedaView;
        NavigationController.PushViewController(x, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using **NavigationController** to navigate :

```
NavigationController.PushViewController(secondViewController, true);
```

You can use follow way back to previous vontroller:

```
 NavigationController.PopViewController(true);
 //or specify the needed controller 
 NavigationController.PopToViewController(previousController, true);
```

If using **Model View** to navigate to the next controller as follow:

```
PresentModalViewController(secondViewController, true);
```

You can use the follow way to back to previous controller:

```
DismissModalViewController(true);
```

================================update #1=============================

If using `NavigationCotroller` to navigate, the condition that it should be the **root controller**.

For example in **.StoryBoard** :

[image]

or in **.cs** code as follow:

```
...
this.Window.RootViewController = new UINavigationController(xxxController);
...
```

Comment: In theory I should navigate so I use the first portion of your code, but the return to previous page function does not appear the same, indeed the page does not even load ..